# Google places api error in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using google places api in ionic app.I places google places api script in index.html. The app allow the user to access wifi within specific place. User get internet access after login with our app. When application launch and user is connecting with our network, user do not have access to the internet. So i get error:

**Application Error connection to the server was unsuccessful.**

Is there anyway to call the google places api after user has access to the internet to avoid the error?

Comment: you can use for example the [network plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) for this

Comment: @Kaddath i put the google api in index.html. So how can i use this plugin? because index.html execute first when apps start.

Comment: i'll write an anwser, won't fit in a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been quickly tested in ionic 1 and it works, no reason it shouldn't in ionic 2. But if you know a proper way to add the script tag in angular, just replace this part. The logic is simply to add your resource on the fly to index.html. Don't forget that connexion can appear while app is already started, and that you don't need to add the tag twice (verifications have to be done). Some edits might be done to adapt to ionic 2, sorry my version was made on the 1.

the function to add the script:

```
function addScriptTag(){
    //STORE HERE VALUE TO VERIFY SCRIPT HAS ALREADY BEEN ADDED
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://maps.google.com...';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

in $ionicPlatform.ready (network is not available before that)

```
//CONNECTED AT APP LOADING
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
if(networkState !== Connection.NONE){
    addScriptTag();
}

//IN CASE CONNEXION ARRIVES LATER
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
    if( /* VERIFY SCRIPT NOT ADDED BEFORE */ ){
         addScriptTag();
    }
}, false);
```